# rails draw datatable after 50 rows jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, datatables

currently, I am getting 50 records from database and adding them to datatables.

```
@users = EvercamUser.all.includes(:country, :cameras).limit(50).order("created_at desc").decorate
```

but after page load am sending an ajax request and getting all other thousands records and rendering them to javascript page where datatables are initiated.

what i want to do is to draw datatable after first 50 rows which are already present on page load and want to draw all other row after ajax success.

i tried `users_table.fnAddData(data)` but it rewrite the whole `datatable` where as i want to load after 50 rows.

datatable configuration

```
users_table = undefined

initializeDataTable = ->
  users_table = $("#users_datatables").DataTable
    aaSorting: [1, "asc"]
    aLengthMenu: [
      [25, 50, 100, 200, -1]
      [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
    ]
    columns: [
      {data: "0" },
      {data: "1" },
      {data: "2" },
      {data: "3" },
      {data: "4" },
      {data: "5" },
      {data: "6" },
      {data: "7" },
      {data: "8", visible: false },
      {data: "9" }
    ],
    iDisplayLength: 50
    columnDefs: [
      type: "date-uk"
      targets: 'datatable-date'
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Filter:"
    },
    initComplete: (data) ->
      $("#user-list-row").removeClass('hide')
      $("#users_datatables_length label").hide()
      $("#div-dropdown-checklist").css('visibility', 'visible')

columnsDropdown = ->
  $(".users-column").on "click", ->
    column = users_table.column($(this).attr("data-val"))
    column.visible !column.visible()

onPageLoad = ->
  $(window).load ->
    data = {}
    data.true = true
    $.ajax
      url: 'users'
      data: data
      type: 'get'
      dataType: "json"
      success: (data) ->
        users_table.fnAddData(data)
```

Comment: why not just clear the datatable and load all ajaxed values?

Comment: if table will be cleared then the already  loaded values  will be cleared as well..
whole data loading took time so we divide it into 2 queries. so first 50 will be shown at once others can wait.

Comment: what notation is this `->` ?

Comment: this is coffeescript buddy.. var test = function(){} in coffee test = ->

Comment: you mean anonymous function, you may trigger the ajax on a new page of the datatable and load the corespunding 50 values of that page

Comment: no i dont mean that.. am on the same page and loading it when it will be laod 50 be shown at once anc remaining will come after succes of ajax

Comment: then in the ajax db query skip the first 50 and append the data to the datatable, redraw the datatable